# How to calculate total number of days in between two dates in groovy

Tags: groovy

How to calculate total number of months and year in  between two dates in groovy

```
date1 =2012 nov 1
date2 =2013 feb 1
```

required output is  year = 0 and month =3.
 Any answer is helpful

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116936/how-to-find-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-java-or-groovy

Comment: I really want the total no: of months and years between two dates.

Comment: Doesn't that depend on the length of a Month?  Which depends which months are inside the range? Months are not uniform in length

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do:

```
monthBetween = (start[Calendar.MONTH] - end[Calendar.MONTH]) + 1
yearsBetween = start[Calendar.YEAR] - end[Calendar.YEAR]
months = monthBetween + (yearsBetween * 12)
```

Taken from [Calculate difference in months between two dates with Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820022/calculate-difference-in-months-between-two-dates-with-groovy)