# Groovy, Grails; add +1 to a variable each week

Tags: grails, groovy

Imagine that you need to add +1 to an integer "meetingWeek" everyweek, every week you have one meeting.
How do you do this?

I was thinking of having a date "startDate" and the integer "meetingWeek",
so e.g.

```
startDate= 2014/04/07
meetingWeek = 3 (We already had 3 meetings for example)
```

Then:

```
weekDif = todayDate-startDate
totalWeeks = weekDif + meetingWeek
```

If we are at 2014/04/14 ("todayDate"), the result must be meetingWeek=4; also must be 4 for the rest of the week.
If we are at 2014/04/21-25, the result must be meetingWeek=5

So in groovy I can do something like this:

```
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
   def weekDif = todayDate-startDate
   println "days: ${weekDif.days}, Hours: ${weekDif.hours}"
}
```

How can I get the weeks?

Comment: Maybe some example inputs and expected outputs would help explain the problem?

Comment: Yes you are right, I will take your hint for this and my next questions... Sorry and thank you tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore my previous answer.  This one should work fine -

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory
import java.lang.Math
def dateParser = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd")
def startDate = dateParser.parse("2014/04/04").getTime()
def futureDate1 = dateParser.parse("2014/07/04").getTime()
def futureDate2 = dateParser.parse("2015/07/04").getTime()
def meetingSeed = 3
def millisInWeek = 604800000
def futureDate1Weeks = Math.floor((futureDate1 - startDate)/millisInWeek)
def futureDate2Weeks = Math.floor((futureDate2 - startDate)/millisInWeek)

println("Future Date 1 weeks - " + (futureDate1Weeks + meetingSeed))
println("Future Date 2 weeks - " + (futureDate2Weeks + meetingSeed))
```

Comment: I didn't know it could be broken. So theoretically this will work, also with different years? I am going to try it, thank you

Comment: Above should work as long as future date > start date

Comment: Nice it is working, just what I needed, thank you very much Joseph. Sorry to ask, but doing the same thing with months instead of weekends I could use a new "millisInMonth" ?

Comment: With months I used: [another so question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820022/calculate-difference-in-months-between-two-dates-with-groovy)

Comment: Months won't work because there is a different amount of time in each month.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
def today = new Date()
def start = today + 45
def meetingWeek = 1

( today..start ).step( 7 ) { meetingWeek++ }

println meetingWeek
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(todayDate);
    int week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(startDate);
    int week2 = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

def todayMeetingWeekNumber = (week-week2) + meetingWeekSeed
```

Imagine the values:

```
startDate= 2014/04/07
meetingWeekSeed = 3
```

Input:

```
2014/04/14
2014/04/15
2014/04/21
```

Output:

```
4
4
5
```

Comment: Be careful... not sure if this is for an assignment or for work, but if its for work, the Calendar class has a lot of bad dark corners related to threading.

Comment: This is going to break if the year is changed.  For example, `2015/01/01` is going to return a value of `1`.  So your result will be a negative value.